# Vader says 'Build another imperial level'. I've already built all 16. Is this a bug?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

As the title says I've been working through the Vader quests and now he's asking me to 'Build another Imperial level to find out what to assemble next!'. I've already built all 16 Imperial levels. Obviously I could skip the quest but that costs 100 Bux, and I would feel exceedingly ripped off to waste 100 Bux on what feels to me like a bug which could happen again.

Have I reached the end of the quests, is that really what's happened here?